# Convert data from one format to another

Tags: python, list, hashmap

I have data in this format:

```
{'a':['b','c','d'],'bla':['djjd','cop']}
```

And I want to convert the above into this format:

```
('a',('b','c','d')),('bla',('djjd','cop'))
```

What can be done in Python to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that turns key value pairs from dictionary to tuples:

```
>>> d = {'a':['b','c','d'],'bla':['djjd','cop']}
>>> [(k, tuple(v)) for k, v in d.items()]
[('a', ('b', 'c', 'd')), ('bla', ('djjd', 'cop'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data is in variable `d`. Then:

```
converted = [(key, tuple(d[key])) for key in sorted(d)]
```